# can't open andoid.bat file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't open android.bat file. 
I already tried:

1. Running the android.bat file as administrator
2. move the AVD and SDK manager from /sdk/tools/lib to the root folder /sdk
3. Just go to SDK zip -> adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip, Unzip the Tools Directory only, copy it under ../sdk/
4. reinstal android studio
5. Copy your android.bat file to C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools folder or copy all files to C:\

Nothing works for me.

I also want to try this one:

6. the same issue when updating the Android SDK Tools and SDK Platform-tools from the SDK Manager. I had to replace the tools folder with one located in a zip folder inside the temp folder.

but itemp folder includes many files and i don't know what to open...

7. I also tried set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java.exe"
   but there is no set java_exe in android.bat file, code is here:

   @echo off
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

   ```
   echo **************************************************************************
   echo The "android" command is deprecated.
   echo For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
   echo For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
   echo and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
   echo **************************************************************************
   echo.

   set DIRNAME=%~dp0
   if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.\

   if not defined wrapper_bin_dir (
     set wrapper_bin_dir=bin
   )

   set avd_verbs=;list;create;move;delete;
   set avd_objects=;avd;target;device;

   call:checkMatch "%avd_verbs%" "%avd_objects%" %* || (
     call:invoke "%DIRNAME%%wrapper_bin_dir%\avdmanager" %* || exit /b 1
     exit /b 0
   )

   set sdk_verbs=;list;update;
   set sdk_objects=;sdk;
   call:checkMatch "%sdk_verbs%" "%sdk_objects%" %* || (
     call:runSdkCommand %* || exit /b 1
     exit /b 0
   )

   echo Invalid or unsupported command "%*"
   echo.
   echo Supported commands are:
   echo android list target
   echo android list avd
   echo android list device
   echo android create avd
   echo android move avd
   echo android delete avd
   echo android list sdk
   echo android update sdk
   exit /b 1

   :runSdkCommand
     setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
     set trysdk=""
     if defined USE_SDK_WRAPPER (set trysdk="%USE_SDK_WRAPPER%")
     call:findSdkParam %* || (
       set trysdk=y
     )
     if %trysdk%=="" (
       echo "android" SDK commands can be translated to sdkmanager commands on a best-effort basis.
       echo (This prompt can be suppressed with the --use-sdk-wrapper commend-line argument
       echo or by setting the USE_SDK_WRAPPER environment variable^)
       set /p trysdkresponse="Continue? [y/N]: "
       if /I "!trysdkresponse!"=="y" (
         set trysdk=y
       )
     )
     if %trysdk%=="" (
       echo Aborted
       exit /b 1
     )
     if "!verb!"=="list" (
       call:invoke "%DIRNAME%%wrapper_bin_dir%\sdkmanager" --list --verbose || exit /b 1
       exit /b 0
     )
     if "!verb!"=="update" (
       set args=
       set prev=
       set update_all=1
       call:sdkUpdate %* || exit /b 1
       exit /b 0
     )

   :sdkUpdate
     setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
     set paramsWithArgument=;-p;--obsolete;-u;--no-ui;--proxy-host;--proxy-port;-t;--filter;
     set verb="%~1"
     set object="%~2"
     set args=
     set prev=""
     shift & shift
     :sdkupdateloop
       if "%~1"=="" (goto:sdkupdatedone)
       set arg="%~1"
       set unquotedarg=%~1
       shift
       if !arg!=="--use-sdk-wrapper" (
         goto:sdkupdateloop
       ) else if !arg!=="!verb!" (
         goto:sdkupdateloop
       ) else if !arg!=="!object!" (
         goto:sdkupdateloop
       ) else if !arg!=="-n" (
         echo "update sdk -n is not supported"
         exit /b 1
       ) else if !arg!=="-s" (
         set args=!args! --no_https
       ) else if !arg!=="--no-https" (
         set args=!args! --no_https
       ) else if !arg!=="-a" (
         set args=!args! --include_obsolete
       ) else if !arg!=="--all" (
         set args=!args! --include_obsolete
       ) else if "!paramsWithArgument:;%unquotedarg%;=!" neq "!paramsWithArgument!" (
         rem nothing
       ) else if "!arg:~1,1!"=="-" (
         echo Unrecognized argument !arg!
         exit /b 1
       ) else if !prev!=="--proxy-host" (
         set args=!args! --proxy=http --proxy_host=!unquotedarg!
       ) else if !prev!=="--proxy-port" (
         set args=!args! --proxy_port=!unquotedarg!
       ) else if !prev!=="-t" (
         set has_filter=y
         call:parseFilter !arg! || exit /b 1
         rem unquoted comma-separated lists are treated as separate args, so if
         rem the next arg isn't recognized as a flag, treat it as a filter element
         goto:sdkupdateloop
       ) else if !prev!=="--filter" (
         set has_filter=y
         call:parseFilter !arg! || exit /b 1
         rem unquoted comma-separated lists are treated as separate args, so if
         rem the next arg isn't recognized as a flag, treat it as a filter element
         goto:sdkupdateloop
       ) else (
         echo Unrecognized argument !arg!
         exit /b 1
       )
       set prev=!arg!
       goto:sdkupdateloop

     :sdkupdatedone
     if not defined has_filter (
       set args=%args% --update
     )
     call:invoke "%DIRNAME%%wrapper_bin_dir%\sdkmanager" %args% || exit /b 1
     exit /b 0

   :parseFilter
     for %%i in (%~1) do (
       set filter=%%i
       if "!filter!"=="tool" (
         set args=!args! tools
       ) else if "!filter!"=="tools" (
         set args=!args! tools
       ) else if "!filter!"=="platform-tool" (
         set args=!args! platform-tools
       ) else if "!filter!"=="platform-tools" (
         set args=!args! platform-tools
       ) else if "!filter!"=="doc" (
         set args=!args! docs
       ) else if "!filter:~0,4!"=="lldb" (
         set args=!args! !filter:-=;!
       ) else if "!filter:~0,11!"=="build-tools" (
         set args=!args! !filter:build-tools-=build-tools;!
       ) else if "!filter!"=="ndk" (
         set args=!args! ndk-bundle
       ) else if "!filter:~0,8!"=="android-" (
         set args=!args! platforms;!filter!
       ) else if "!filter:~0,6!"=="extra-" (
         set tmp=!filter:extra-=extras-!
         set args=!args! !tmp:-=;!
       ) else (
         echo Filter !filter! is not supported
         exit /b 1
       )
     )
     exit /b 0


   :findSdkParam
     :sdkloop
       if "%~1"=="" ( exit /b 0 )
       set arg=%~1
       shift

       if "%arg%"=="--use-sdk-wrapper" (
         exit /b 1
       )
       goto:sdkloop

   :checkMatch
     set verbs=%~1
     set objects=%~2
     set verb=""
     set object=""
     shift & shift
     :loop
       if "%~1"=="" ( goto:done )
       set arg=%~1
       shift
       if "%arg:~0,1%"=="-" ( goto:loop )
       if !verb!=="" if "!verbs:;%arg%;=!" neq "!verbs!" (
         set verb=!arg!
         goto:loop
       )
       if !verb! neq "" if "!objects:;%arg%;=!" neq "!objects!" (
         set object=!arg!
         goto:done
       )

     :done
     if !verb! neq "" if !object! neq "" exit /b 1
     exit /b 0

   :invoke
     echo Invoking %*
     echo.
     call %* || exit /b 1
     exit /b 0
   ```

Comment: Running a .bat file under Windows from command prompt is pretty standard. Why dont you manage? You are not talking about errors and such. Or what happens instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the `android.bat` code, the `android` command is **deprecated**. You need to use Android Studio when updating all related to Android SDK.

When you try running it, it will give the following message:

```
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

in the Windows, you need to run the `android.bat` inside the command prompt. The above message is when running the `android` script in Linux. But the result should be relative same.